# Efficient nested optimization of several hundred equations in R

Tags: r, optimization, iteration

I'm trying to figure out a more efficient way to analyze a data set with 4 independent variables (x1, x2, x3, and x4) and 1 response variable (y, which can be any number between 0 and 1). I'm trying to fit my data to a model with 6 parameters (3 slopes [m1, m2, and m3] and 3 intercepts [b1, b2, and b3]).

The y response at each point is calculated by solving for y where the following equation equals zero:

```
-x4+(x1/((log(-y/(y-1))-b1)/m1))
          +(x2/((log(-y/(y-1))-b2)/m2))
          +(x3/((log(-y/(y-1))-b3)/m3))
```

As far as I know (and please correct me if there is a better way), the best way to accomplish this is by minimizing the absolute value of the above equation with `optimize()`. Here is a reproducible example with arbitrary parameters and x values:

```
#model parameters
b1=-8
b2=-10
b3=-15
m1=2
m2=25
m3=50

#independent variables
x1=3.9
x2=.02
x3=.01
x4=1

a=function(y) abs(-x4+(x1/((log(-y/(y-1))-b1)/m1))
      +(x2/((log(-y/(y-1))-b2)/m2))
      +(x3/((log(-y/(y-1))-b3)/m3)))

y=optimize(a,c(0,1))
```

With these inputs, y evaluates to ~0.617.

Easy enough, but I have to do this for each of the 500 data points (each with a unique x1, x2, x3, x4 combination, but all with the same parameters b1, b2, b3, m1, m2, and m3). I'm currently using `vapply()`, but it seems like there's got to be a more efficient way. However, I'm not aware of a way to vectorize optimization problems.

If it ended here, it wouldn't be so bad (all 500 points are evaluated with `vapply()` and `optimization()` in less than a second). But this only calculates the y variables for one given set of parameters. The problem arises when I try to optimize the parameters b1, b2, b3, m1, m2, and m3 using `DEoptim()` to maximize log-likelihood (and then I use the parameters from `DEoptim()` as starting parameters for parameter fine-tuning in `optim()`). Needless to say, since every parameter iteration requires the evaluation of 500 optimization problems, this takes a while. Oddly, when I manually run vapply for optimizing one set of parameters (i.e., the equivalent of a single iteration for DEoptim), it takes less than a second, but each iteration for `DEoptim()` (which should also take less than a second) takes about 10 seconds. I don't know why `vapply()` takes so much longer (any thoughts?), but I'm hoping there's a way to solve all 500 equations more efficiently.

Before resorting to `vapply()` and `optimize()`, I tried a few alternative methods, including iterative calculation of y (at all 500 points simultaneously) using `Reduce()` (instead of `optimize()`), and it was a bit faster (~6 seconds per iteration), but I think I should be able to achieve <1 second per iteration (as in when I run one instance of `vapply()` manually). If I can't find a better alternative, I'll probably go back to `Reduce()`.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: *To clarify, the specified equation gives the predicted y value (where the equation equals zero) at each point for specified parameters and x values (total of 500 data points consisting of unique combinations of x1, x2, x3, and x4, so there are 500 unique y values to calculate; y is the only unknown in each instance). The overall goal is to optimize the parameters via maximum likelihood to obtain predicted y values that best fit the observed y values. At every iteration of parameter optimization, the 500 y values must to be re-calculated, because the m1 m2 m3 and b1 b2 b3 parameters have changed.*

Comment: Please confirm: The parameters are known and `y` is unknown and not part of your data?

Comment: If you let `z=log(y/(1-y))`,
your equation is of the form 
`u0 + u1/(z-a) + u2/(z-b) + u3/(z-c) = 0`;
solving it is equivalent to finding the roots of a polynomial of degree 3.
Check `?polyroot` or use the [exact formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Roots_of_a_cubic_function).

Comment: Zoonekynd's comment is excellent;  in a more general case you might have success with the `BB` package.  I also would suggest that in many cases, it's simpler and more efficient to spline (or similar tool) the data itself, rather than forcing optimization of the theoretical equation set.

Comment: I tried the `BB` package and `dfsane` in particular. No solution found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use a square as objective function instead of abs() since then the first derivatives are continuous. You can see this by doing

```
curve(a,.001,.999)
```

and by leaving out the abs and defining this function

```
b=function(y) -x4+(x1/((log(-y/(y-1))-b1)/m1))+
              (x2/((log(-y/(y-1))-b2)/m2))+
              (x3/((log(-y/(y-1))-b3)/m3))
```

and graphing this function

```
curve(b,0.001,.9999)
```

Generally speaking it is not a good idea to find the solution of a system of equations with an optimization algorithm since that looks for any minimum (global and local).
You want a minimum that is 0.

So it's better to use a nonlinear equation solver.
There's a package `nleqslv` that does that (Note: I am the author of that package).

There is no need to use `Vectorize` or other methods of vectorizing since your function is already vectorized.

Define a function `f` (same as your `a` without `abs` and slightly more efficient)

```
f <- function(y) {
    tmp <- log(-y/(y-1))
    -x4+(x1/((tmp-b1)/m1))+(x2/((tmp-b2)/m2))+(x3/((tmp-b3)/m3))
```

}

and define a function for calculating the jacobian

```
fjac <- function(x) { h <- 0.00001*x; diag((f(x+h)-f(x))/h) }
```

which can be done very efficiently since each element of the return value of `f` only depends on the corresponding element of the input vector `y`.

For each parameter configuration, data vector and a starting value for `y` the solution for your `y` can be calculated by

```
z <- nleqslv(ystart,f,fjac, method="Newton")
y <- z$x
```

You must use method `Newton` since method `Broyden` won't work in this case.
You can try this example

```
K <- 500
x1 <- x1 + c(0,runif(K-1,.1*x1,.3*x1))
x2 <- x2 + c(0,runif(K-1,.01*x2,.03*x2))
x3 <- x3 + c(0,runif(K-1,.01*x3,.03*x3))
x4 <- x4 + c(0,runif(K-1,.01*x4,.03*x4))
nleqslv(rep(.3,K),f,fjac, method="Newton")
```

On my computer this takes about 0.08 seconds.

Comment: This works really well for medium to large values, but I can't seem to get it to work for smaller values. For instance, 
`K <- 500
x1 <- seq(.01,10,.02)
x2 <- seq(.001,1,.002)
x3 <- seq(.0001,.05,.0001)
x4 <- rep(1,500)`
yields a range of y values from ~.3 to ~1.0. It doesn't seem to be reaching the y values closer to zero. If I lower the starting value to .1, then my values range from ~0.1 to ~1. However, if I lower the starting value to .01, the values range from ~0 to ~0.14. Any thoughts?

Comment: Set `x1=.01 x2=.001 x3=.0001 x4=1` and do `curve(f,0.001,.9999)` and you will see that there is no solution. You should check the `termcd` component of the return value of `nleqslv`. You will have to analyze the equation to determine when it has a solution f(y)=0.

Comment: Good point, I was inadvertently asking `nleqslv()` to do the impossible. For very small x values, the solution at these points where the solution would normally exist apparently approaches infinity instead. This issue never manifested with optimization of the absolute value, because the solution _approached_ zero, which worked for my purposes (albeit quite slowly). It seems that adding `solution[is.infinite(solution)]=0` to function f takes care of it. I'll need to check to make sure this is a robust solution, but it seems to be the **much** more efficient answer I was looking for. Thanks!!